# substring extraction in salesforce apex not working how I expected it too

Tags: apex-code, salesforce-service-cloud

So I am trying to auto-populate a *subject* and *comments* case field in a salesforce case object based of information that is passed through our *description* field.

currently we are assuming the structure of said description will look something like this:

```
“
Subject: test-emailtocase2
Internal Comments: this is second attempt as case trigger
…
“
```

so far my code for the substring looks like:

```
c.Subject = c.Description.substringAfter('Subject: ').substringBefore('Internal Comments: ');
c.Comments = c.Description.substringAfter('Internal Comments: ').substringBefore('\n');
```

the issue i am encountering is that the subject field populates just fine, but for some reason the comments field doesn't populate, and I've tried a couple different configurations.

~to my knowledge I believe my field name references are correct

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, why not just use carriage returns?

```
String tempString = 'Subject: test-emailtocase2' + '\n' + 'Internal Comments: this is second attempt as case trigger\n' + '…';

String[] splitup = tempString.split('\n');
String subject = splitup[0].replace('Subject: ', '');
String comments = splitup[1].replace('Internal Comments: ', '');

System.debug(subject);
System.debug(comments);
```